# Could anybody help me with ableton live lite 9 and softube Plugins .

Tags: ableton-live, homerecording, ableton

I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit pro and Ableton live lite 9 and softube time and tone bundle (64 bit) . But Softube plugins are not visible in Ableton. Any solutions for this ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> (a) Launch Ableton Live and go to:
>
> Windows: Options > Preferences Mac: Live > Preferences
>
> (b) Select the File/Folder tab, and under Plug In sources, toggle Use
>   VST Plug-In Custom (Win)/System Folders (Mac) off and on again.
>
> (c) Hold down the [Alt/Option] key and click Rescan.

Source: http://www.waves.com/support/how-to-find-your-plugins-in-ableton-live

Comment: I have tried this but still facing same issue .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed the plugins in the correct VST folder?

Is your Ableton Live Lite 32-bit or 64-bit? Please refer to the help article below to verify you installed your plugins correctly and they match your Ableton version (you need to install 64-bit plugins only if you use 64-bit version of Ableton).

> 32-bit plug-ins won't show up in the 64-bit version of Live and vice versa.

Refer to this article: https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/209071729-Recommendations-for-using-VST-plug-ins-on-Windows

Comment: Yes I installed correctly and I am using Ableton live lite 64 bit with 64 bit plugins n i am using windows 8.1 64 bit .

Comment: when I use 64 bit plugins with Ableton 32 bit then it works , But after installing Ableton 32 bit I cannot use Amplitube and guitar Rig plugins :(

Comment: Let me know where you installed these two plugins and what is the Ableton setting for 64-bit plugins. Some plugins are by default installed into dedicated folders in Program Files but their .dll files (which are recognized by Ableton) should be placed into _VstPlugins_ folder. If you installed these plugins with an installer, maybe there were two steps during the installation process: 1. Plugin dependent files folder (installation folder); 2. Plugin DLL folders for 32-bit and 64-bit versions.